# How to show full contents with horizontal scrollbar in an HTML layout with fixed header and footer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML layout has fixed header and footer. The middle container is composed of left pane (also fixed position) and right pane. The right pane is the area where the contents will be displayed, and it should be able to show vertical and horizontal scrollbar depending on the screen size.

Here is my test fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mo0rjye3/2/

[image]

When I resize the width of the screen, the table shifts to the left, and some parts get hidden from view.

**Expectation:** Table should be fully displayed with horizontal scrollbar and at the same time it should be centered in the allocated space for the right pane (width will be dynamically calculated based on the widest content). For example, the width of the right pane can be 1200px, and the contents should be center-aligned inside.

If I don't use the `display: flex` in `div-centered` class, the table is displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove positions on main and sidebar-left. 
Add display:flex to container.
Display div in the table as block.
Add some bootstrap col classes to container, main and sidebar to get the style. Please refer to the fiddle.

```
#sidebar-left{  
  margin-top: 30px;
  min-width: 230px;
  height: 87vh !important;
  min-height: 50vh !important;
  background-color: coral;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

#main{
    background-color: lightgray;  
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 87vh !important;
    min-height: 87vh !important;
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 87vh !important;  
}

#container{
  display: flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bL3h1gvu/